# Modifying each value of array with immutability helper

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, immutability

I'm struggling to figure out what the best practice is to modify each value in an array of objects using the [immutability helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

For example, if I were to have this in my state:

```
this.state = {
    items: [
        {
            name: "test",
            subItems: [
                {val: false}, {val: true}, {val: false}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "test2",
            subItems: [
                {val: true}, {val: true}, {val: false}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to set every `val` to `false`, how might I do that.

I could do it one at a time, but there must be a better way:

```
let elements = update(this.state.items, {
  [idx1]:{
    subItems:{
      [idx2]:{
        val: {
          $set: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It certainly is possible, but it's everything but readable or understandable at first sight.

```
const nextState = update(state, {
    items: {
    $apply: (items) => {
        return items.map(item => {
        return update(item, {
            subItems: {
            $apply: (subItems) => {
                return subItems.map(subItem => {
                return update(subItem, {
                    val: {
                    $set: false
                  }
                })
              })
            }
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you want to set a combination of false and true bools as oppose to setting all to false? Any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

For an ES6 solution with immutability, [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and no helpers:

```
this.setState({
  // This is if you have other state besides items.
  ...this.state,
  items: this.state.items.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    subItems: item.subItems.map(subItem => ({
      ...subItem,
      val: false // or e.g. setter as a function of (item, subItem)
    }))
  }))
});
```

is easier on my eye than the update helper.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.state = {
    items: [
        {
            name: "test",
            subItems: [
                {val: false}, {val: true}, {val: false}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "test2",
            subItems: [
                {val: true}, {val: true}, {val: false}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

use functional programming

```
this.state.items
.filter((item) => item.name === test).subitems
.map((subItem) => {
  subitem.forEach( (key) => {
   { [key]: !subitem[key] }

})
})
```

Comment: I assume the OP wants to update `this.state`, but this doesn't return a full state to replace the old with.